# Removed fieldname id and reformat JSON Output in golang

Tags: json, rest, go

I am developing a rest api using golang based on `/v1/public/characters` of [Marvel API](https://developer.marvel.com/docs). I need to return all the character ids in the format of

```json
[ 1011234, 1012345, 1009213, 1010788, 1087123, 1222345, ... ]
```

The way I achieve this is via `strings.NewReplacer` (in last 2 lines below).

```golang
...

type CharacterId struct {
    Data struct {
        Results []struct {
            Id int `json:"id"`
        } `json:"results"`
    } `json:"data"`
}

func getCharacters(w http.ResponseWriter, _ *http.Request) {
    ts := strconv.FormatInt(time.Now().Unix(), 10)
    hash := getMd5(ts + conf.privateKey + conf.publicKey)

    response, err := http.Get("https://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/characters?ts=" + ts + "&apikey=" + conf.publicKey + "&hash=" + hash + "&limit=100")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer response.Body.Close()

    responseBytes, err := ioutil.ReadAll(response.Body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    var characterId CharacterId
    err = json.Unmarshal(responseBytes, &characterId)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
        return
    }

    data, err := json.Marshal(characterId.Data.Results)
    replacer := strings.NewReplacer("\"id\":", "", "{", "", "}", "", ",", ", ", "[", "[ ")
    fmt.Fprint(w, replacer.Replace(string(data)))
}
```

Without using `strings.NewReplacer` like the code snippet above, i.e. `fmt.Fprint(w, string(data))` directly gives me the output below which is not what I want.

```json
[{"id":1011334},{"id":1017100},{"id":1009144},{"id":1010699},{"id":1009146},{"id":1016823},{"id":1009148},{"id":1009149}, ... ]
```

I somehow feel my way of using `strings.NewReplacer` is not a clean/proper way. Can anyone suggest a better way of making the output I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create `int array` with your IDs and marshal it and write it to your response.

Replace your last tree lines with following code and test.

```
    var data []int
    for _, result := range characterId.Data.Results {
        data = append(data, result.Id)
    }
    c , err := json.Marshal(data)
    if err != nil {
        //handle error here
    }
    fmt.Fprint(w, string(c))
```